# Detecting Class object equivalence for classes loaded by different ClassLoaders

Tags: java, reflection, classloader, equals

My Task is to write a unit test for a method `findSubClassImplementation` that returns an instance for a given Class object. The method signature looks like this:

```
public <T extends SuperClass> T findSubClassImplementation(Class<T> cls) throws Exception
```

Internally the method checks wether the supplied Class object belongs to a set of known classes and then returns an instance of that class:

```
if (Subclass.class.equals(cls)) 
        return (T) new Subclass(args);
```

If the class is not known, an Exception is thrown. **This code is given**

I tried to load all Classes inheriting from `SuperClass` via Reflection and then pass them as argument to `findSubClassImplementation`:

```
Set<Class<? extends SuperClass>> subTypesOf = reflections.getSubTypesOf(SuperClass.class);
Class<? extends SuperClass> clazz = subTypesOf.iterator().next();
SuperClass instance = findSubClassImplementation(clazz);
```

I then use a Debugger to step into the method, and I can see the line of code where

```
if (Subclass.class.equals(cls))
```

returns false, although `cls = Subclass.class`

I assume what happens is this: `Class` does not implement equals, thus equals of `Object` is used, that compares with "==". As reflection uses a different ClassLoader than is used in `findSubClassImplementation` the two class Objects are different. Is this assumption correct?

Is it possible to get the other Class object for a class that I have loaded with Reflection? Do you have another idea how to deal with this problem?

**ANSWER:**

Turns out I am not very good at reading: The hirarchy is in 3 levels: SuperClass --> IntermediateAbstractClass--> Subclass. The comparison is always to the intermediate abstract class:

```
if (IntermediateAbstractClass.class.equals(cls)) return (T) new Subclass(args);
```

Thus my question wasn't very accurate or precise - I am sorry if you feel like I wasted your time. I'll mark Michael Wiles answer as the correct one, because his advice pushed my to discover my missunderstanding. Thank you!

Comment: You say "As reflection uses a different ClassLoader than is used in findSubClassImplementation the two class Objects are different." - what do you mean by this? Are you saying the the findSubClassImplementation method uses a different class loader than used to load the class passed in? The reason I ask is that reflection does not by default use a different classloader to the "current" classloader...

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I'll edit the question to describe the situation more precisely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be something that is different about the classes...

You say that Subclass.equals(otherSubclass) returns false we need to ascertain why this is the case.

Check the name of each class for equality and then check the classloader of each class for equality.

Based on your provided code to do the reflection there is nothing here to sugggest that these classes loaded by "Reflection" are in fact loaded from different classloaders.

Furthermore try all sorts of classes, maybe there is something unique about that particular class that causes the behaviour.

One suggestion to try would be to add Integer to the subclass set and then pass in Number to the method...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't need to check what class is `cls`, since `cls` already contains all the information you need. Try simply with

```
public <T extends SuperClass> T findSubClassImplementation(Class<T> cls) throws Exception {
    // ... retrieve args
    final Class<?>[] constructorParamTypes = new Class<?>[args.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        constructorParamTypes[i] = args[i].getClass();
    }
    return cls.getConstructor(constructorParamTypes).newInstance(args);
}
```

Or in the Java 8 way:

```
public <T extends SuperClass> T findSubClassImplementation(Class<T> cls) throws Exception {
    // ... retrieve args
    final Class<?>[] constructorParamTypes = Arrays.stream(args).map(Object::getClass)
            .toArray(size -> new Class<?>[size]);
    return cls.getConstructor(constructorParamTypes).newInstance(args);
}
```

Comment: Your approach would work beautifully if my task would be to implement findSubClassImplementation. However: that code is given.I need to write a test, that will fail as soon as someone changes that code in a significant way. I'll edit the question to make it more obvious that this code is given